# Adding different List<string> to DataGridViewComboBoxCell in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

I am having trouble implementing DataGridViewComboBoxCell inside the DataGridView control. What I want to do is to display in every row different set of choices – so each ComboBox has a different list to display. I am using Visual Studio designer.

I have assigned to myDataGridView.DataSource the BindingSource (variable name is bindingSourceComponenetFileInfo) to which DataSource (bindingSourceComponentFileInfo.DataSource) I have assigned my data called EclipseComponentFileInfo which is defined like this:

```
namespace EclipseSuiteMakerWindowsForms
{
    class EclipseComponentFileInfo
    {
        public EclipseComponentFileInfo()
        { }
        private string path;
        private string pathName;
        private string[] fileName;
        public string[] FileName { get => fileName; set => fileName = value; }
        public string Path { get => path; set => path = value; }
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is the ‘filename’ field – because it is not a plain string but an array of strings, it does not appear in Visual Designer under DataGridView/Columns/SelectedColumns (only PathName column is available). I used Visual Designer to create for my DataGridView an ‘Unbound column’ (which I still don’t quite understand what it is and how it works – no docs) specifying as ‘Name: FileName/Header text: FileNameHeader /Type:DataGridViewBoxColumn’ and then when I run my app, my ComboBox column in every row came up as an empty string – I kind of expected that.

So next I assigned (using Visual Designer) to the DataSource of the unbound column created above (DataGridViewBoxColumn.DataSource) variable (of type BindingSource) called fileNameBindingSource. Next I have assigned to ‘fileNameBindingSource .DataSource’, the earlier mentioned bindingSourceComponenetFileInfo (of type EclipseComponentFileInfo) with the DataPropertyName called FileName.

Then all rows’s ComboBox columns are filled with the name that appears in the first row for some reason.

My question is:

Can I have rows of  ComboBox columns filled with different set of items or every ComboBox has to have the same set of items (e.g first row has ComboBox with array of one item “Item1”, but the second row has a comboBox with the array of two items “Item1/Item2”).

Answer (score 0):

The list of items doesn't come from the grid's data source. Generally speaking, you set a data source for the column and each cell inherits that. If you want a different list for each cell though, you need to set a different data source for each cell.

Comment: How do I do that using Visual Designer?

Comment: ... or even programmatically when everything else has been set using Visual Designer?

Comment: You don't do it in the designer because the cells don't exist at design time. You can set column properties at design time but cell properties cannot be set until cells exist. Probably the simplest option is to create a single list contain all options, bind that to the column and then filter the list for each cell when editing. I'll provide an example of that.

Comment: @Rejkid Perhaps try using the `DataBindingComplete` event handler for this.  There, you can iterate through the rows and set the `ComboBox` according to whatever logic you need.

Comment: Thanks OhBeWise for the reply, but my problem is not that combo boxes are empty - each combo box has exactly the right items in it. However when my app runs the very first time, each combo box displays the value of the first combo box. For example if I have two rows with one column which is a combo box and the first combo box has one element Item1 and the second combo box has two elements Item2/Item3 the when my app appears on the screen, both rows for some reason display Item1 (even though the second combo box does not even have Item1 in its list).

Comment: Hi  jmcilhinney you have promised me the sample code, could you provide one please?

Comment: Any response please?

Comment: jmcilhinney - Any update on when you might have your code example?, although I also have started to experiment with my code - I have learned the field I have problem with (FileName ) is an unbound column  - does it change anything?